# Timer does not countdown in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I am building a simple stopwatch app in ReactJS (count down to 0).
So far I have an input where the user can set how long the timer should be and a button which updates the timer state with the input data.
However I am not able to have the timer countdown, even with using setInterval().

App.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Timer from './timer';
import './app.css';
import { Form, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timerPosition: '',
            newTimerPosition: '',
          };          
    }

startTimer() {
    this.setState({timerPosition:this.state.newTimerPosition})
}

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="App-title"> Stopwatch </div>
        <Timer timerPosition={this.state.timerPosition} />
        <Form inline>
        <FormControl 
        className="Deadline-input"
        onChange={event => this.setState({newTimerPosition: event.target.value})}
        placeholder='Set timer'/>
        <Button onClick={() => this.startTimer()}>Set new timer</Button>
        </Form>
        </div>
        )}



}

export default App;
```

Timer.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './app.css';

export class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        secondsRemaining: ''
         }
    }

componentWillMount(){
    this.startTimer(this.props.timerPosition);
}

componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(() => this.startTimer(this.props.timerPosition), 1000);
}


startTimer(timerCallback) {
    this.setState({secondsRemaining: timerCallback --})
}



render() { 
return (
<div>

<div></div>
{this.state.secondsRemaining} seconds remaining
</div>


)}

}


export default Timer;
```

The timer does not decrement every second and just stays at the original position.

Comment: Please reduce the code in your question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you keep using the same prop value `secondsRemaining`. You decrement the same value in the prop`this.props.timerPosition` each time. So the state value `secondsRemaining` never changes.

Instead decrement the `secondsRemaining` value from state using the `setState` method which takes a callback. The first parameter of the callback is the current state. so you do:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return { secondsRemaining: prevState.secondsRemaining - 1 };
  });
```

You also need to set your initial state value to the supplied props value:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({ secondsRemaining: this.props.timerPosition });
    ... other code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is counting down now, however it is ignoring the original state (timerPosition). So if I input something into the form (updating timerPosition), the secondsRemaining state is not updated. I would appreciate your further help.

Comment: You need to set up the initial state by setting ```state.secondsRemaining``` (using setState) from the supplied props value in ```componentWillMount```. I'll update my answer

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue is in the interval callback in `Timer`'s `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(() => this.startTimer(this.props.timerPosition), 1000);
}
```

Note that you're constantly reusing `this.props.timerPosition` as the timer position, instead of using the current state. So you're setting the state back to the initial state from the props.

Instead, you want to use the current state. *How* you use that state will depend on how you want the timer to behave, but beware of two things:

1. Never call `this.setState({foo: this.state.foo - 1})` or similar. State updates are asynchronous and can be combined. Instead, [pass a callback to `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).
2. Nothing is guaranteed to happen at any particular time or on a specific interval, so don't just decrement your counter; instead, see how long it's been since you started, and use that information to subtract from your initial counter value. That way, if your timer is delayed, you still show the correct value.